# How to process VUMeter on VSTGUI?

Tags: audio-processing, vst

I'm on Xcode 4.5 and can't get a simple VU Meter working on VSTGUI. 
I found no documentation for how to send values from the process loop to the CVuMeter Function.

I opened a thread at KVR a time ago:
[VUMETER and GUI](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=367440)

The code I used, works good, no issues or errors on build. 
BUT: I can't get it working till now. What's the problem within this code? The VU Meters won't update....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are not telling VSTGUI to update the editor after setting the value. You might want to check out the [again example code](http://read.pudn.com/downloads119/sourcecode/multimedia/audio/506335/vstsdk3/public.sdk/samples/vst/again/source/againeditor.cpp__.htm) which ships with VSTGUI. The vumeter stuff is at the bottom of that class.

Comment: Yes. checked it already. But it's VST3. Before I get hands on VST3 I have to know how this will work on VST2, I think...

Comment: it's all about Xcode 4.5. I'm back to Xcode 3 and it works. Coding on XCode is really a challenge.....